# How to echo something if no input is made and enter pressed?

Tags: batch-file

How do I set a windows batch script to echo something if no input is made for a selection and enter is pressed. E.g.

```
@echo off
title Thingy
:home
cls
echo.
echo =================
echo Thingy
echo =================
echo Choose An Option
echo =================
echo.
echo 1) Thing.exe With Stuff
echo 0) Exit
echo.
set /p web=Type an Option:
if "%web%"=="1" goto thing1

thing1:
set /p stuff="Enter stuff: "
thing.exe -load %stuff%
```

And if nothing is entered upon "enter stuff", and just enter is pressed, how do I set it to echo something?

Like I would like 
"echo No input entered, running thing.exe without any stuff"

Comment: Simply select your code and click `{}` to format as code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an IF statement to determine whether the input is empty:

```
set /p stuff="Enter stuff: "

IF "%stuff%"=="" (
    ECHO No input entered, running thing.exe with no args
    thing.exe
) ELSE (
    thing.exe -load %stuff%
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if not defined web echo Nothing entered?&pause&goto home
```

or

```
if not defined web echo Nothing entered?&goto alabl\eljustbeforetheset_slash_p
```

or

```
if "%web%"=="" goto somewhere
```

Note that pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> leaves the variable *unchanged* so

```
set "web=somedefaultvalue"
set /p "web=Some prompt text "
```

can be used to assign a default used if <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone is used and

```
set "web="
set /p "web=Some prompt text "
```

is preferable if no default is applicable; it ensure that the variable is set to *nothing*, not any previous value it may have had.

should cure your problem.

Comment: Forgive my stupidity. This is literally my first time ever writing any kind of script or similar. I have no idea where to put those commands. Where *exactly* would they go?

Comment: We all have to start somewhere. Welcome to the oddball world of `cmd` scripts!